# Propriedade Delphi

Tags: delphi, propriedade

Tenho um componente que tem a função de conectar a um hardware especifico. Ele se conecta através da rede ou porta serial. Algo parecido como o código abaixo:

```
  TConexao = (conRede, conSerial);

  THardware = class(TComponent)
  private
    FAtivo: Boolean;
    FPortaSerial: string;
    FTipoConexao: TConexao;
    FPorta: Integer;
    FIP: string;
    procedure SetAtivo(const Value: Boolean);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Ativar;
    procedure Desativar;

  published
    property Ativo: Boolean read FAtivo write SetAtivo;
    property TipoConexao: TConexao read FTipoConexao write FTipoConexao;
    property IP: string read FIP write FIP;
    property Porta: Integer read FPorta write FPorta;
    property PortaSerial: string read FPortaSerial write FPortaSerial;
  end;
```

Para conectar através da rede utilizo as propriedades IP e Porta e para conectar pela serial utilizo somente porta serial. No Object Inspector ao definir TipoConexao para Rede gostaria que mostrasse somente as propriedades IP e Porta, se fosse mudado para Serial mostrasse somente a propriedade PortaSerial. É possível?

Comment: Olá Patrick, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Você está querendo alterar quais serão as propriedades visíveis de acordo com o tipo de conexão? Se for isso, você pode [edit] a pergunta adicionando esta informação para deixar claro para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Opa! Pergunta alterada @PageNotFound

Comment: Não é possível. Você poderia desabilitar o preenchimento das informações através do Get e Set. Ex: GetIP, SetIP e implementar o controle dentro desses métodos. Uma outra forma é criar 2 componentes para configuração, e utilizá-los por composição dentro da sua classe. Dessa forma, você controla  a instanciação de um ou outro dependendo do caso

Comment: Obrigado @Caputo Isso mesmo. Já alterei a pergunta.

Comment: @PageNotFount no caso eu definiria no Set do TipoConexao a destruição e criação desses componentes?

Comment: Se você optar por essa forma, sim.

Comment: Caro @PageNotFound adicionei os dois componentes como sugerido e ao definir o TipoConexao defini a criação do componente associado e funciona de forma satisfatória, obrigado pela dica. O único porém é que a propriedade ainda fica visível, não podendo ser alterada. Você tem alguma outra alternativa?

Comment: Qual o problema de ela ser exibida?

Comment: A forma mais correta seria criar um editor de propriedades customizado, herdando de TPropertyEditor. Leia este [artigo](http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc092501a.htm). Nesse editor customizado você pode fazer o que quiser, inclusive um Form com um seletor com as suas opções e configurar painéis para serem mostrados a cada opção. Ao escolher as opções e defini-las, aplique-as ao componente em tempo de execução. Pesquise mais utilizando o termo PropertyEditor

Comment: Lembre-se de certificar se suas definições estão sendo salvas quando você fecha o Delphi e o abre novamente.

Comment: Ok, obrigado!!!

Comment: Que tal fazer desta forma? Isso parece uma situação tipica de Interfaces. http://www.devmedia.com.br/desmistificando-as-interfaces/347

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Então!! Seguindo as dicas do @PageNotFound fiz da seguinte forma:

Primeiro criei um componente para cada conexão:

```
  TRede = class(TComponent)
  private
    FPorta: Integer;
    FIP: string;
  published
    property IP: string read FIP write FIP;
    property Porta: Integer read FPorta write FPorta;
  end;

  TSerial = class(TComponent)
  private
    FPorta: string;
  published
    property Porta: string read FPorta write FPorta;
  end;
```

Depois adicionei as propriedades no componente principal:

```
  THardware = class(TComponent)
  private
    FAtivo: Boolean;
    FTipoConexao: TTipoConexao;
    FRede: TRede;
    FSerial: TSerial;

    procedure SetAtivo(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetTipoConexao(const Value: TTipoConexao);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Ativar;
    procedure Desativar;

  published
    property Ativo: Boolean read FAtivo write SetAtivo;
    property TipoConexao: TTipoConexao read FTipoConexao write SetTipoConexao default conRede;
    property Rede: TRede read FRede write FRede;
    property Serial: TSerial read FSerial write FSerial;
  end;
```

E no SetTipoConexao defini qual componente deve estar ativo, assim:

```
procedure THardware.SetTipoConexao(const Value: TTipoConexao);
begin
  if FTipoConexao <> Value then
  begin
    case Value of
      conRede:
      begin
        FreeAndNil(FSerial);
        FConexao := TRede.Create(self);
        FConexao.Name := 'Rede';
      end;
      conSerial:
      begin
        FreeAndNil(FRede);
        FConexao := TSerial.Create(self);
        FConexao.Name := 'Serial';
      end;
    end;

    FTipoConexao := Value;
  end;
end;
```

Lembrando de criar os componentes no create e destruí-los no destroy.
Obrigado a todos!

Comment: O .dfm está salvando suas opções ao fechar/abrir o delphi novamente?

Comment: @PageNotFound Sim, as alterações nas propriedades estão ficando armazenadas no .dfm.